# Net socket closing

Tags: node.js

Im fairly new to back end development, comming from front-end i picked up node as back end. I created very simple chat based on book im reading. the code is quite simple .

```
var net=require("net");
var sockets=[];
var server=net.createServer();
    server.on("connection",function(socket){
        console.log("new connection");
        socket.write("hi");
        sockets.push(socket);
        socket.on("data",function(data){
            console.log("got: "+data);
            sockets.forEach(function(otherSocket){
                if(otherSocket!==socket){
                    otherSocket.write(data)
                }
            });
        });
        socket.on("close",function(){
            console.log("socket closed");
            var index=sockets.indexOf(socket);
            sockets.splice(index,1)
        })
    });
    server.on("error",function(error){
        console.log("error :");
    })
    server.on("close",function(){
        console.log("server has closed");

    })
server.listen(8888); //server.listen(4001)
```

I am running this code in node e.g node example.js , 
basicly it returns

```
new connection
new connection
got: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0
.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: sk-SK,sk;q=0.8,cs;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2


socket closed
```

as you can see , the socked closed but why does socket automaticly close here? does it automaticly close after all data was sent? Also my localhost wont load here , while it do load with http.createServer.
Lastly , as for this being primitive chat, how would i test it if its working well. I tried opening cmd and run this multiple times but it always throw erro (except first time)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the socket was closed by the client, as you're not sending a valid HTTP response. I assume that you want to use browsers for the chat frontend; but your example uses raw TCP sockets, which means you'd have to use something like telnet. You should take a look at WebSockets, which works in browsers (if you actually want to build a chat app for browser clients).